# how could I create a firefox plugin to auto fill forms using SDK

Tags: javascript, forms, firefox, plugins, autocomplete

```
var tabs = require("sdk/tabs");

tabs.on('ready', function(tab) {
  var worker = tab.attach({
      contentScript:
        'document.body.style.border = "5px solid red";'
  });
});
```

by this way,seems that I can run a jscript file in a tab.But I don't know how to locate username and password [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XqlqX.jpg). I notice that chrome could auto fill if I choose to remember password. How can I do this in firefox with a plugin?

I tried

```
function getElements(){
  var x=document.getElementsByTagName("input");
  console.log(x.length);
  for (var i=0;i<x.length;i++){
    console.log(x[i].type);
    if (x[i].id=='username'){
      x[i].value='haha';
    }
  }
}
```

to fill a username by `contentScript`,but it seems jscript does't run.And I can't find the log.Please give me a tip.Thanks:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally,I find a way to inject js to current html and locate (username,password) well.

at index.js

```
var tabs = require("sdk/tabs");
  tabs.activeTab.attach({
    contentScriptFile:self.data.url("login.js")
  });
```

at Jscript:

```
  var x=document.getElementsByTagName("input");
  var temp;
  for (var i=0;i<x.length;i++){
    if (x[i].type=='password'){
      temp.value='haha';
      x[i].value='yes';
    }
    temp=x[i];
  }
```